# How to stringify the values of json search for content in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

I have document like follow, I want full text search (`values` only) is it possible to convert object into string in rethinkdb?
I would like to have something like `r.table('x')('description').contains('commonwealth')` I don't know have many or what children will be there. so first convert all values of child node into a single string and then search the text(or other way also). 
Thank you

```
{
  "description": {
    "parlist": [
      {
        "listitem": {
          "text": {
            "bold": "their",
            "child": "odds hope best purse claim",
            "emph": "commonwealth crows philip duke wench imagination longaville worthiness father grey"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work, but it's probably not super efficient

```
r.table('x').filter(function(doc) {
    return doc('description').coerceTo("STRING").match("commonwealth")
})
```

Comment: cool! I didn't know you could coerce the whole object. I still think something like elasticsearch is a better fit though. But I'm a big fan of rethinkdb.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to pull this off with map/reduce, I've done something similar in the past. I'll try to update this answer with an example of such later.

But I would highly recommend using the right tool for the job, and it sounds like what you want is [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/). It runs alongside your database and gives you much better search tools. It would far exceed anything you could do with map/reduce and it would be faster.

Comment: problem with ES is , it is Java , and adding another stack is a memory hog.

Comment: @V3ss0n - neumino gave the OP exactly what he asked for. But RethinkDB will be a CPU hog, and eventually search requests will pile up if the OP uses the method from neumino. Which is worse?